# Существует ли карта Google maps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

По клику добавляю карту

```
$("body").on("click", ".search_show_map", function(){
    $("#result_search").html('<div class="search_result_map" id="map_canvas" style="width:100%;height:500px"></div>');
    var map;
    function initMap() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        zoom: 8
      });
    }
    initMap();
});
```

Можно ли как нибудь проверить существует ли на странице карта, а то  при повторном клике Вместо карты серый фон

Comment: Есть две кнопки показать результаты:  "На карте" и "Списком". Как сделать так чтобы при клике на "Списком" удалялась карта, потом по клику на "На карте" подгружалась?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вынесите `var map;` за пределы обработчика. Затем внутри обработчика проверяйте значение на `undefined`

```
var map;

$("body").on("click", ".search_show_map", function(){
    $("#result_search").html('<div class="search_result_map" id="map_canvas" style="width:100%;height:500px"></div>');
    function initMap() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        zoom: 8
      });
    }
    if (map === undefined) {
      initMap();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно проверить кол-во созданных блоков:

```
$("body").on("click", ".search_show_map", function(){
    if($("#result_search .search_result_map").length == 0){
        $("#result_search").html('<div class="search_result_map" id="map_canvas" style="width:100%;height:500px"></div>');
        var map;
        function initMap() {
          map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
            center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
            zoom: 8
          });
        }
        initMap();
    }
});
```